# HDFS Data Export error: could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Tags: hadoop, qubole

After succussefully running an Hive Query when Data Export to MySQL starts in Qubole, I am getting the following error (in my log file):

> org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException: java.io.IOException: File
>   /tmp/mapred/system/CAR/libjars/tmp_clickimpressiontracking.jar4047410322917561880
>   could only be replicated to 0 nodes, instead of 1

Comment: can you post the complete trace.

Answer (score 0):

Have seen this issue when DFS replication factor is set to 2 and you have just a one (slave) node in the cluster at that point. Sharing more specifics can help us get better answers. Drop a note to our support email id mentioned on our support portal with the specific command id etc, we can take a look.

-Venkat (Qubole Support)